# Top-level about Page in Django error

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'd like to have a top-level about page in my Django site `(eg: http://127.0.0.1:8000/about)` that's pointed to the class based about view in the polls app or a top-level about page, however I'm getting:

```
TypeError at /about/
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

MySite/Mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'myPollSite.views.index', name='myPollSite_home'),
    url(r'^about/$', 'myPollSite.views.AboutView', name='myPollSite_about'),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace = "polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

]
```

MySite/Mysite/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import generic

class AboutView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "polls/about.html"


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at myPollSite index.")
```

MySite/polls/template/polls/about.html:

```
<h1>About Page</h1>
<h2>Implemented with TemplateView</h2>
<p>
    No Model Data can be retrieved with Template View
</p>
```

Comment: Your url should be like this: myPollSite.views.AboutView.as_view()

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/#subclassing-generic-views), configure your class-based view with an `as_view()` call:

```
url(r'^about/$', AboutView.as_view(), name='myPollSite_about'),
```

where `AboutView` should be imported:

```
from myPollSite.views import AboutView
```

Comment: AboutView.as_view () worked, but how come when I used myPollSite.views.AboutView.as_view(), I got a NameError: "myPollSite" is not defined?

Comment: @jerryh91 I think you should have just imported `myPollSite`. Should work as the option I've provided.